# Unable to login a custom user using CBV in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-custom-user

While trying my luck with Class Based views in Django, I am unable to get a custom user logged in.

Here is my view:

```
class Loginview(FormView):

    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': LoginForm})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect('dashboard')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return render(self.request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

My form:

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

My model:

```
class Company(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

FYI  this is a custom model and has a separate user Manager.
Whenever I submit the login template with the email and password fields, it returns me a form error saying that email and password do not match while they should be matching.

Answer (score 0):

Django has authentication [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-forms) that handle logging in. It's easier to use these rather than write your own.

If you must write your own view and form, then you'll have to check the user's password and then log them in. See the docs on [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for more info.

Comment: But those default views won't be able to handle my custom user and that is why I was creating/overriding the default LoginView

Comment: Why do you think the views/forms can't handle your custom user? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) say that the authentication form is compatible with any subclass of `AbstractBaseUser`. In any case, I've linked to [how to log a user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) to show you how you do it without the built-in forms/views. As an aside, are you sure you need to subclass `AbstractBaseUser`? You won't have as much to customise if you subclass `AbstractUser`.